# Read line containing specific text in a shell script variable

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I have a variable in shell script which looks like this below. Each line separated by a new-line character.

```
var="This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
/home/usr/new/foo.txt
This is the forth line
This is the fifth line"
```

Now I need to read the line which contains `.txt` in it and store it in another variable.

```
another_var=/home/usr/new/foo.txt
```

Comment: Worked like charm, thank you :)

Comment: Appreciate you finding it useful. Also could you update the question with relevant efforts you tried, so that it would be helpful in the future?

Comment: I think `grep` could select lines... As in `var2="$(echo "$var" | grep '.txt$')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most recent versions of `bash` you should have `mapfile` command available which allows you to parse a multi-line string. We parse the string into an array and match the line containing the glob string `.txt` and print it as

```
mapfile -t new_array <<< "$var"

for element in "${new_array[@]}"; do 
    if [[ $element == *".txt"* ]]; then
        new_var="$element"
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more generic.

```
#!/bin/bash

var="This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
/home/usr/new/foo.txt
This is the forth line
This is the fifth line"

dog="$( echo "$var" | grep txt )"
echo $dog
```

I used bash but I believe this would work with ksh as well.

I didn't notice Zsigmond already suggested this.